# Merging dataframes based on different subets

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

```
DF <- mtcars
```

```
## subsets

df1 <- subset(DF, carb == 1)
df2 <- subset(DF, am == 1)
```

```
## table

table1 <- prop.table(with(df1, table(cyl, gear)), margin = 1)
table2 <- prop.table(with(df2, table(cyl, vs)), margin = 1)
```

```
## total

total <- cbind(table1 , table2)
```

which results in:

```
Error in cbind(B5A2, B5A3) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I'm trying to merge (preferably by cols ) those 2 data frames (table1 , table2) based on two different subets (df1, df2) from the mtcars dataset. I've tried so far: convert to  `data.frame`  and use  `bind.cols`  and  `plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(table1, table2)`  which both didn't work. Is there a way to fix this?

The preferred output should look like this:

```
cyl   3   4     0     1
  4 0.2 0.8 0,125 0.875
  6 1.0 0.0 1.000 0.000
  8         1.000 0.000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `cbindX` function from the `gdata` package:

> cbindX column-binds objects with different number of rows.

Code:

```r
DF <- mtcars
df1 <- subset(DF, carb == 1)
df2 <- subset(DF, am == 1)

table1 <- prop.table(with(df1, table(cyl, gear)), margin = 1)
table2 <- prop.table(with(df2, table(cyl, vs)), margin = 1)

library(gdata)
cbindX(table2, table1)
#>       0     1   3   4
#> 4 0.125 0.875 0.2 0.8
#> 6 1.000 0.000 1.0 0.0
#> 8 1.000 0.000  NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could also construct your frequency tables as actual `tibbles`/data.frames* (I am using `janitor`'s `tabyl` here) and then do a `full join` (I am using `dplyr`).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

table1 <- df1 |> tabyl(cyl, gear) |> adorn_percentages()
table2 <- df2 |> tabyl(cyl, vs) |> adorn_percentages()

table1 |> full_join(table2)
```

Output:

```r
 cyl   3   4     0     1
   4 0.2 0.8 0.125 0.875
   6 1.0 0.0 1.000 0.000
   8  NA  NA 1.000 0.000
```

(*) When you write "2 data frames (table1 , table2)", you're not completely right. Your tables are tables, not data frames, which is not the same. Using `as.dataframe(table)` will give you the data in the `table` organized in another format better suited for other kinds of analysis.